# Visual Studio 2012 installation without SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've got a question regarding Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktop. It installed many "SQL Server (...)" items on my PC. Since I don't use any SQL servers when programming in c# I wonder if I can safely uninstall these (or install a fresh copy of vs without them).

Thanks.

Comment: +1 most developers prefer using the Dev Edition of SQL Server and like you avoid installing Express Ed, a tip if you do use SQL in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server is not needed for Visual Studio.  Blow it away if you don't use it -- especially if you don't even access any databases.

Answer (score 3):

Careful here.
Visual Studio's IntelliSense (pretty central tool, a must have when not broken by other reason..) will require Microsoft SQL Server Compact(4.0 for VS 2012) to run properly.

At least do not uninstall Microsoft SQL Server Compact.

Comment: I removed all SQL components, including SQL Server Compact, and it did not affect my installation of Visual Studio 2013 Professional. I can still use IntelliSense and GoTo/Peek definition without issue. I do not develop with any SQL components, and I have yet to find any drawback to removing all of the SQL items. I suppose your mileage may vary, but this was not an issue for me.

Comment: Intellisense may keep running fine without SQL Server Compact for C# projects, however MFC based workspaces need an SQL Server Compact database.

Answer (score 0):

If you put in Professional or greater, it also installed SQL Server Compact Edition, the Windows CE version.  You really have two instances at that point, Express and Compact.

Probably the better thing to do is set these services to Manual so that they don't start automatically when you turn on your computer.  Otherwise, leave them alone.  It's highly likely that you will, at some point, need them, and at that point it might bother you to have to spend a couple of hours downloading and carrying out the installation cycle.